# javascript creating data object from 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

I have 2 arrays already setup within the js:

varDepth:

```
[0.5, 1.75, 2.38, 2.74, 2.89]
```

varMins:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm looking to create an object (chartData1) to push and this is the format of the array:

```
chartData1.push({'x': varDepth[i][0], 'y': varMins[i][1]});
```

But I cannot get this to work, I think I'm missing the setting up of the object, Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add the desired outcome.

Comment: You say `charData1` is an object... you mean an array or a key-value object? Both of your arrays are 1-d so the offset makes no sense.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you're trying to access `varDepth` and `varMins` as if they are multidimensional arrays? Either your understanding of Arrays in JavaScript is flawed, or you haven't adequately represented the data as it exists in actuality within your script.

Comment: I know I'm missing the loop section:
for (var i=0; i < run1Inputs; i++) {

output should look like:

{x:0,y:0},{x:1,y:0.5},
       {x:2,y:1},
       {x:3,y:1},
       {x:4,y:1}

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29668874) to show that information as a [mcve] of your code attempt, with syntactically valid input and expected/actual output.

Comment: Sorry, that posted prematurely...
The output should end up like:
{x:0.5,y:0},{x:1.75,y:1},{x:2.38,y:2},{x:2.74,y:3},{x:2.89,y:4}

Comment: `varDepth.map((x, i) => ({x, y: varMins[i]}))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to create multiple objects who's data are from the same indexes in both arrays; you can;

1. Loop over one of the arrays (I'm using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) so we can return the created objects into an array)
2. Add value to a new object
3. Add value of the other array, on the same index

```js
const depths = [ 0.5, 1.75, 2.38, 2.74, 2.89 ];
const mins = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ];

let result = depths.map((depth, index) => ({ x: depth, y: mins[index]}))
console.log(result);
```

```json
[
  {
    "x": 0.5,
    "y": 0
  },
  {
    "x": 1.75,
    "y": 1
  },
  {
    "x": 2.38,
    "y": 2
  },
  {
    "x": 2.74,
    "y": 3
  },
  {
    "x": 2.89,
    "y": 4
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you 0stone0 - that is superb...